# What is a viable development pattern with Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm leaning to using Azure API Management to manage/authorize/throttle an application I'll be developing. My question is around a pattern for dev/test.

Should I build it all, then work API Management into the end stages, completely ignoring testing for Authentication? Or is there a 'lightweight' version to exercise it locally?

Typically I'd use something like Identity Server and have my own ID server in the project or stood up somewhere else...but what I've seen, this is much more complicated with APIM

Comment: If you are about to creating your application, how about adding `manage/authorize/throttle` module by developing code yourself? I mean that it seems that you have some custom requirements and apim is a little bit expensive.

Comment: I'm thinking I'd have to leave my API methods undecorated with the [Authorize] attribute, then programmatically apply Authorization if it's *NOT* env.IsDevelopment and then create custom HttpClient to inject depending if IsDevelopment or not, one applying API credentials and one not.